# Right-align a button in a QTreeView column

Tags: python, pyqt, alignment, qtreeview, qpushbutton

I'm trying to align a button to the right side of a QTreeView column in PyQt, and I haven't been successful so far.

`setTextAlignment()` didn't work, and neither did

```
setData(3, QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
```

(By "didn't work" I mean that the button is still left-aligned in the column).

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is by using a container widget with a horizontal layout. You can then set the required alignment on the layout.

Here is a basic demo:

[image: screenshot]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setRootIsDecorated(False)
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['ID', 'Value', ''])
        model.appendRow([
            QtGui.QStandardItem('001'),
            QtGui.QStandardItem('Blue'),
            QtGui.QStandardItem('')
            ])
        self.setModel(model)
        index = model.index(0, 2)
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Delete')
        self.setAlignedWidget(index, button, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

    def setAlignedWidget(self, index, widget, align=QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft):
        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(container)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.setAlignment(align)
        layout.addWidget(widget)
        self.setIndexWidget(index, container)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(['Test'])
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 50, 400, 75)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```